# Duplicate messages while logging in Python, while using FastAPI

Tags: python, logging, fastapi

I am developing an API using FastAPI, and am currently in the process of developing the logging tools. Whenever I get an error message, it shows up in the terminal two times. If I `logger.propagate = False`, the messages only appear once, but the format I define in the configuration doesn't work, I just get the message as output.
main.py:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.exceptions import RequestValidationError
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse, PlainTextResponse

from starlette.exceptions import HTTPException as StarletteHTTPException

from constants import APIWMS001, APIWMS002, APIWMS003, APIWMS004, APIWMS005, APIWMS999, LOGGING
from router import router
from methods_common import CustomLogRecord

import logging
from logging.config import dictConfig

app = FastAPI()

app.include_router(router)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logging.setLogRecordFactory(CustomLogRecord)

dictConfig(LOGGING)

##################################################
##DO NOT FORGET TO ADD FLOW_ID TO JSON RESPONSES##
##################################################

@app.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)
def validation_exception_handler(request, exc):
    for error in exc.errors():
        match error["type"]:
            case "missing":
                return JSONResponse(APIWMS002, status_code=400)
            case "string_type":
                return JSONResponse(APIWMS003, status_code=400)
            case "json_invalid":
                logger.warning("Error 400: JSON format error")
                return JSONResponse(APIWMS001, status_code=400)
            case _:
                return PlainTextResponse("Generic error, behaviour currently undefined")

    return PlainTextResponse(str(exc.errors()))

@app.exception_handler(StarletteHTTPException)
def http_exception_handler(request, exc):
    if exc.detail == "Not Found":
        logger.error("oops")
        return JSONResponse(APIWMS004, status_code=404) #it is needed to always indicate the status_code, otherwise it will respond with 200
    elif exc.status_code == 405:
        logger.warning('Error 405: Method not allowed')
        return JSONResponse(APIWMS005, status_code=405)
    elif exc.status_code == 500:
        return JSONResponse(APIWMS999, status_code=500)
```

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'simple_debug': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s %(module)s %(id)s | %(message)s',
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'd':{
            'level': logging.DEBUG,
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple_debug',
        },
        'e':{
            'level': logging.ERROR,
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple_debug'
        },
        'w':{
            'level': logging.WARNING,
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple_debug'
        }
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['d', 'e', 'w'],
        'level': logging.DEBUG,
    },
}
```